# Measuring code performance bottlenecks of a live IIS website?

Tags: .net, performance, iis, iis-7, profiling

Knowing and using .NET memory and performance profilers (like e.g. RedGate's ANTS Profiler) very well in my *development environment*, I still found no real way to do it on a *production server*.

Currently I'm experiencing every now and then 100% CPU usage of w3wp.exe for a certain application pool.

Looking at various performance counters, I'm still unable to determine the real cause, since I cannot determine in which part of my code the high CPU utilization takes place.

I've tried [CLR Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650691.aspx#scalenethowto13_topic2) on the live server (with no meaningful result) and I even could imagine installing ANTS Profiler and let it run for hours to get some measurement logs.

Just to be sure I'm doing it right, **my question is**:

What is the best way to do some ad hoc measurements on a production IIS 7 web server to detect code bottlenecks?

Comment: More specific metric counters might be interesting. For example, do you see a spike in "%Time in GC" or "% Time in Jit" that coinside with the CPU spikes?

Comment: @vcsjones Thank you. Even _if_ I have these information, I'm totally clueless how I would ever be able to map them to source code lines so that I could improve the source code.

Comment: I've just found [LeanSentry](https://www.leansentry.com/) which sounds like a good tool, although I did not try it yet and it seems kind of "dead" (last blog entry from over a year ago and pricing table says "© 2013" together with some "coming soon"s).

Comment: @UweKeim what solution did you end up with? I'm seeing cpu spikes with my asp.net app, and not sure where to start... Tried New Relic - no useful data there :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having asked the question also in the Red Gate's ANTS Profiler forum, I got a [great reply from the developers](http://www.red-gate.com/MessageBoard/viewtopic.php?p=52810#52810):

Basically the pointed me to the Early Access Program (EAP) version of version 7 of ANTS Profiler. This one has a feature that they call "continuous profiling" which basically does a live trace of a IIS worker process.

I'll give this tool a try since it seems to be exactly what I want to have.

Answer (score 2):

Although you've answered your own question, I just wanted to mention [Gibraltar](http://www.gibraltarsoftware.com/).

I haven't used it myself, but I've heard good things about it.

Comment: Thanks, Nicholas, I know these guys from their VistaDB database. The tool you mention looks more like a log management tool, not like something I'm able to use to find performance issues down to the source code level?!?

Comment: AFAIK, it can also track performance counters and custom code metrics using PostSharp. It might help you narrow down your search. I just found this [video](http://www.gibraltarsoftware.com/See/PostSharp.aspx)

Comment: Gibraltar includes application metrics - performance counters and your own metrics around things like database calls, key transitions in your application, etc.  Out of the box it also records a metric for every web hit breaking the time down by the ASP.NET pipeline. We're glad to help you get up and running and I think you'll find our pricing options are quite competative.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be tempted to adopt something line New Relic's APM product - will allow you to monitor both the real user experience (page load times), servers and the application itself

Have a look at this for more details: http://newrelic.com/docs/dotnet/new-relic-for-net

Comment: Thanks, @Andy - do you have (good/bad) personal experiences with the tool?

Comment: I've not used it in a .net environment (used other mix of other tools that never quite quite provided a complete picture). Have used it in other environments and found it to be very good - they do a trial  if you want to try it.

Answer (score 1):

Sam Saffron (one of the StackoverFlow creators) has created a great command-line tool a while ago, but unfortunately has abandoned it.

A friend of mine has forked the code to make it work in 2015:

https://github.com/jitbit/cpu-analyzer

(the page has a link to Sam's blog post explaining how to use it)

Comment: Thanks. I know Sam as one of the core Discourse developers.